# Detect display change of input inside ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an `input` inside a `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf='display'>
    <input number="number" />
</div>
```

I would like to detect when the `input` is displayed or not inside the number directive. Meaning that when `display=true` and change to `false`, it should call a function inside the directive as well as when it goes back to `true`.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jGLwXSxXHk2OhQuvrEpe?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+ - Set ngModel to null when ngIf causes hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979046/angular-2-set-ngmodel-to-null-when-ngif-causes-hide)

Comment: I tried to post my answer here, but it got flagged as a duplicate post, so I'm flagging this as a duplicate so that people can find my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `number` directive is created every time `display` changes from `false` to `true` and destroyed when `display` changes from `true` to false.

For the former case you can use the `constructor(...)`, `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()`, or `ngAfterContentInit()`,

for the later `ngOnDestroy()` can be used.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I'm not using an `*ngIf` but a conditional css `hidden` attribute. Would you have a solution in that case?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to figure out if an element is visible. Perhaps iterating the parents to see if one has `visibility=='hidden'`. Probably a better way would be to pass `display` to `number` as well and make an input like `@Input() set if(value) { if(value) {...} else {...}}` and then use it like `<input number="number" if="display" />`